# How to decrease the size of the text input in Ionic2 and align the label on the right side

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2

I want to decrease the width of the text input and align the label on the right side. By default, Ionic is placing the label on the left side.

```
 <ion-item>
        <ion-label>pounds</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="number"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
```

I tried various things in css to fix the input length like below :

```
  .item.item-input>input{
    width:30%;
  }
```

But none of them is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that if you're trying to wrap it with "ion-item"

This workaround may help you achieve what you're looking for,

```
<ion-row>
     <ion-input type="number" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000;max-width: 50%;"></ion-input>
     <p>pounds</p>
</ion-row>
```

and manually style it like other elements